# Continue executing NSOperation after enter to background

Tags: ios, background, nsoperation

I need to run my long running task until it is finished and it does not matter if the application is gone to the background.
So I have subclass of NSOperation, and I added this NSOperation to NSOperationQueue. In the main function of the NSOperation I have:

```
- (void)main {

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskId = 0;
    taskId = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) {
       [app endBackgroundTask:taskId];
    }];

    NSManagedObjectContext *searchContext = [NSManagedObjectContext createSearchTempContext];

    [searchContext performBlockAndWait:^{

        NSArray *array = //Get Array data from CoreData;

        if (array.count > 0) {

           //Long running task
        }

        if (taskId != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) [app endBackgroundTask:taskId];
    }];
```

Is it all I need to run in the background? Or something I missed?

Comment: Does this not work properly?

Comment: Sometimes, It is looking like NSOperation doesn't work, there is no logs from "Long running part"

Comment: Do you have anything in your pList to designate it to be able to run in the background, like GPS/Music?

Comment: No, I only setup: Background Fetch and Remote notifications in the Background Modes part

Answer (score 0):

UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier  would only be able to give you some extra time to complete your task, it would allow your app to remain alive for maximum 10 mins, then it would go in suspended state, For an APp to run in background there are only few ways possible which are listed as follows

Play audio:
Receive location updates:
Perform finite-length tasks:
Process Newsstand Kit downloads: 
Provide Voice-over-IP (VoIP) services:

If your app dosent use any of these then it will be suspended after 10 mins regardless of all your operations

Comment: 10 min it is more than necessary, I need 1 min, max 2min. Is it my code correct for this case?

Comment: Ok then  UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier  will serve you better, it can run programs untill you finish

Comment: As of iOS 7, the background time limit is 3 minutes (not 10 as it was in previous releases).